# Higher-kinded generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, haskell, polymorphism, higher-kinded-types

Suppose I have the following class:

```
public class FixExpr {
  Expr<FixExpr> in;
}
```

Now I want to introduce a generic argument, abstracting over the use of Expr:

```
public class Fix<F> {
  F<Fix<F>> in;
}
```

But Eclipse doesn't like this:

> The type F is not generic; it cannot be parametrized with arguments <Fix<F>>

Is this possible at all or have I overlooked something that causes this specific instance to break?

Some background information: in Haskell this is a common way to write generic functions; I'm trying to port this to Java. The type argument F in the example above has kind * -> * instead of the usual kind *. In Haskell it looks like this:

```
newtype Fix f = In { out :: f (Fix f) }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this? Could it not be more easily solved using a template?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is simply not supported by Java generics. The simpler case of

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public T<String> bar() { return null; }
}
```

also does not compile using javac.

Since Java does not know at compile-time what `T` is, it can't guarantee that `T<String>` is at all meaningful. For example if you created a `Foo<BufferedImage>`, `bar` would have the signature

```
public BufferedImage<String> bar()
```

which is nonsensical. Since there is no mechanism to force you to only instantiate `Foo`s with generic `T`s, it refuses to compile.

Comment: It is not directly supported by Java but you can still encode that concept in Java's type system. See my answer below.

Answer (score 27):

Maybe you can try Scala, which is a functional language running on JVM, that supports higher-kinded generics.

---

**[ EDIT by [Rahul G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192247/missing-faktor) ]**

Here's how your particular example roughly translates to Scala:

```
trait Expr[+A]

trait FixExpr {
  val in: Expr[FixExpr]
}

trait Fix[F[_]] {
  val in: F[Fix[F]]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to pass a type parameter, the type definition has to declare that it accepts one (it has to be *generic*). Apparently, your `F` is not a generic type.

UPDATE: The line

```
F<Fix<F>> in;
```

declares a variable of type `F` which accepts a type parameter, the value of which is `Fix`, which itself accepts a type parameter, the value of which is `F`. `F` isn't even defined in your example. I think you *may* want

```
Fix<F> in;
```

That will give you a variable of type `Fix` (the type you did define in your example) to which you are passing a type parameter with value `F`. Since `Fix` is defined to accept a type parameter, this works.

UPDATE 2: Reread your title, and now I think you might be trying to do something similar to the approach presented in ["Towards Equal Rights for Higher-Kinded Types"](https://web.archive.org/web/20091229052347id_/http://www.cs.kuleuven.be/%7Eadriaan/files/higher.pdf) (PDF alert). If so, Java doesn't support that, but you might try Scala.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? I have declared the type to accept a type parameter -- Fix<F>. Or is this not what you mean?

Comment: But the type you have picked - <Fix<F>> - is not generic; it only works for Fix<f> - you should declare it as type <Fix>, surely?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not well-versed in type theory, so it's been heavy going so far, but it is quite interesting. I'm glad I found your question this morning or I might never have read the paper.

Comment: Seconding the suggestion you look at Scala. You can intermix Scala and Java fairly freely, so it's easy enough to dip in your toes.

Comment: re "intermix freely": probably won't be able to use a Scala higher kinded type from Java though.

Answer (score 2):

Still, there are ways to encode higer-kinded generics in Java. Please, have a look at [higher-kinded-java project](https://github.com/sviperll/higher-kinded-java).

Using this as a library, you can modify your code like this:

```
public class Fix<F extends Type.Constructor> {
    Type.App<F, Fix<F>> in;
}
```

You should probably add an `@GenerateTypeConstructor` annotation to your `Expr` class

```
@GenerateTypeConstructor
public class Expr<S> {
    // ...
}
```

This annotation generates ExprTypeConstructor class.
Now you can process your Fix of Expr like this:

```
class Main {
    void run() {
        runWithTyConstr(ExprTypeConstructor.get);
    }

    <E extends Type.Constructor> void runWithTyConstr(ExprTypeConstructor.Is<E> tyConstrKnowledge) {
        Expr<Fix<E>> one = Expr.lit(1);
        Expr<Fix<E>> two = Expr.lit(2);

        // convertToTypeApp method is generated by annotation processor
        Type.App<E, Fix<E>> oneAsTyApp = tyConstrKnowledge.convertToTypeApp(one);
        Type.App<E, Fix<E>> twoAsTyApp = tyConstrKnowledge.convertToTypeApp(two);

        Fix<E> oneFix = new Fix<>(oneAsTyApp);
        Fix<E> twoFix = new Fix<>(twoAsTyApp);

        Expr<Fix<E>> addition = Expr.add(oneFix, twoFix);
        process(addition, tyConstrKnowledge);
    }

    <E extends Type.Constructor> void process(
            Fix<E> fixedPoint,
            ExprTypeConstructor.Is<E> tyConstrKnowledge) {

        Type.App<E, Fix<E>> inTyApp = fixedPoint.getIn();

        // convertToExpr method is generated by annotation processor
        Expr<Fix<E>> in = tyConstrKnowledge.convertToExpr(inTyApp);

        for (Fix<E> subExpr: in.getSubExpressions()) {
            process(subExpr, tyConstrKnowledge);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you may want something like:

```
public class Fix<F extends Fix<F>> {
    private F in;
}
```

(See the Enum class, and questions about its generics.)

Comment: Hi Tom, that solution looks really interesting but I don't really get yet what it does. Doesn't that impose some hierarchy on F? I don't want to do that -- all I ask of F is that it still receives a type argument to be complete.

Comment: if thats the case, then it is not possible in java to do what you want - the language is not expressive enough.

Comment: It says that F is a type of Fix. Because Fix is generic it needs to be given the correct generic argument. Your question is extremely abstract. I understand Haskell has a complicated type system that is different to Java's. It's not surprising that there is not a 1:1 map for every feature.

Answer (score 1):

There is a roundabout way to encode higher kinded types in Java as pointed out by Victor. The gist of it is to introduce a type `H<F, T>` to encode `F<T>`. This can then be used to encode fixed point of functors (i.e. Haskell's `Fix` type):

```
public interface Functor<F, T> {
    <R> H<F, R> map(Function<T, R> f);
}

public static record Fix<F extends H<F, T> & Functor<F, T>, T>(F f) {
    public Functor<F, Fix<F, T>> unfix() {
        return (Functor<F, Fix<F, T>>) f;
    }
}
```

From here you can go on and implement catamorphisms over initial algebras:

```
public interface Algebra<F, T> extends Function<H<F, T>, T> {}

public static <F extends H<F, T> & Functor<F, T>, T> Function<Fix<F, T>, T> cata(Algebra<F, T> alg) {
    return fix -> alg.apply(fix.unfix().map(cata(alg)));
}
```

See my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mduerig/java-functional/blob/master/src/michid/fun/Free.java) for working code including some example algebras. (Note, IDE's like IntelliJ struggle with the code although it compiles and runs just fine with Java 15).