# Java Generics: Return a Type of another Type

Tags: java, generics

This could be a possible duplicate to another question here but I've searched but couldn't get the question I wanted. Kindly point me to a similar question if any.

Is it possible to return a generic of a generic? Here's what I mean:

```
public <T,K> T<K> myMethod(Class<T> classT, Class<K> classK) {
   //...method implementation
}
```

So If I call this method with a `List` and an `Integer` should work as follows:

```
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = myMethod(List.class, Integer.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a type parameter as a generic type. What you're looking for is to set bounds for your `T` type.

Assuming `T` is used for a type like this:

```
class GenericT<T> {}
```

You can declare your method like this:

```
public <K, T extends GenericT<K>> T myMethod(Class<T> classT, Class<K> classK){
    //...
}
```

This makes `T` and instance of `GenericT` with `K` as type argument.

Comment: Then that means `GenericT` has to extend my intended `T` class. E.g. If I want a `List<Integer>` `List` being my `T` and `Integer` my `K`, `GenericT` has to extend `List` then I pass `GenericT` in `myMethod` as the first argument.

Comment: @Kihats Roughly... you can pass and return any sub-type of `List`: `ArrayList<String> res = myMethod(ArrayList.class, String.class)`. Maybe you should add your real use-case?

Comment: I can't do this `List<Integer> myMethod = myMethod(List.class, Integer.class);` because `T` is bounded to `GenericT`. The compiler is complaining. So I have to make `GenericT` extend `List` so that changes the implementation to: `GenericT myMethod = myMethod(GenericT.class, Integer.class);` which is not generic enough in case I need another type of `T`.

Comment: That's the point of the remark I made in the post (*assuming `T` is used for a type like this...*). If you intend to use `List<Integer>`, then the method should be declared as `public  <K, T extends List<K>> T myMethod(Class<T> classT, Class<K> classK)`. You'd of course have to find the uppermost common generic type to use as upper bound for `T`.

Comment: Oh, sure. I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, that can't work. In order to write `T<K>`, `T` would have to be a higher kinded type constructor, but those are not available in Java. Attempts to do it anyway [exist](https://medium.com/@johnmcclean/simulating-higher-kinded-types-in-java-b52a18b72c74), but they seem more like a purely theoretical exercise. See also [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876948/higher-kinded-generics-in-java) for further discussion.