# Can we define generic type with concret type?

Tags: java, generics

I wrote two classes look like this

```java
class SomeClient {

    ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> getSome(...) { // SomeResponse is a concrete class
    }

    ResponseEntity<SomeOtherResponse> getSomeOther(...) { // SomeOtherResponse is a concrete class
    }
}

class SomeReactiveClient {

    Mono<SomeResponse> getSome(...) {
    }

    Mono<SomeOtherResponse> getSomeOther(...) {
    }
}
```

These two methods in each classes has same name and parameters. And only diffs for their return type.

Can I define an interface with an generic type parameter for `ResponseEntity` and `Mono`?

Say,

```java
interface ISomeClass<T> {

    T<SomeResponse> getSome();

    T<SomeOtherResponse> getSomeOther();
}
```

Is there any design pattern for this?

Comment: I think this is called "higher kinded types", which is not available in Java.

Comment: https://medium.com/@johnmcclean/simulating-higher-kinded-types-in-java-b52a18b72c74 seems a bit hacky for me, but maybe it helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Higher-kinded generics in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876948/higher-kinded-generics-in-java)