# Override a method in Java by providing a Subtype as a Parameter

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I want to override a method in Java by passing a concrete subtype of the parameter type that is specified in the super class. See the following example. Is there a way to get this working in Java?

```
    interface A {
        <T> T f(V<T> v);
    }

    interface V<T> {
        T v();
    }

    class B implements A {

        @Override // Here it gives error: Method does not override method from its superclass
        public <T> T f(V1<T> v) {
            return v.v1();
        }
    }

    interface V1<T> extends V<T> { 
        T v1();
    }
```

I have also tried this version for `A` but doesn't work:

```
interface A {
   <T, U extends V<T>> T f(U v);
}
```

Comment: This looks actually impossible, because you can't parameterize on higher-kinded types in Java.

Comment: Can't work because if you casted B back to A and called f with a V, it would have the wrong type as f is overridden to accept V1.

Comment: So what's the workaround here? Use `instanceof` and detect the actual type of `V` at run time?

Comment: @LouisWasserman is it possible to do in Scala or Kotlin?

Comment: Not in Kotlin.  Scala might be possible, I don't know it.

Comment: Doesn't work. Same would be having `A.f(Object o)` then trying to override it as `B.f(String s)`.

Comment: @akarnokd right, I guess I need to rely on runtime checks to detect the actual type if I want to access a specific method there.

Comment: Yes. *(10 chars)*

Comment: Does an implementor of `A` support *all* subclasses of `V<?>`, or is an implementor of `A` required to support only *one* subclass (at their choosing)? If it's the latter, then the generic should be on the interface, because your current code shown makes a very strong guarantee that it sounds like (based on the comments) you didn't intend.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the method `f` in the subclass violates the [*Liskov substitution principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which says that should be able to use a child instance whenever the parent is expected.

```
public <T> T f(V1<T> v)
```

Method `f` in the *parent class* expects `V<T>` as an argument. And `V` is a super type of `V1` which means that the method declared by the *child* expects a more narrow type. I.e. the instance of a *child* is **not** able to handle all subtypes of `V` and hence can't substitute its parent.

And from the practical point of view, it's clearly not a valid *method overriding* (at least in Java). Method signatures should **match exactly**, otherwise it's a *method overloading*, which is the case here.

And you're getting a compilation error because you've applied `@Override` annotation and the compiler fails to find a method with matching signature in the parent class, and also because the contract defined by the interface `A` hasn't been't implemented.

The only exception related to the *overriding* of generic methods that we have is the possibility to *override* a method that expects a generic parameter like `Collection<T>` to be overridden by a non generified method that expects a `Collection` of row type (*it was done in order to facilitate transition to generics when they were introduced in the language*).

Answer (score 0):

You can get close to what you want by taking multiple generic arguments at the interface level and none at the function level.

```
interface A<T, S extends V<T>> {
    public T f(S v);
}

class B<T> extends A<T, V1<T>> {

    @Override // Here it gives error: Method does not override method from its superclass
    public T f(V1<T> v) {
        return v.v1();
    }
}
```

Note that this isn't *quite* the guarantee you were looking for, as someone could come along and write some `class C extends A<Integer, V1<Integer>>` that only works for integers and no other type. But to do that, you'd need something called [higher-kinded polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876948/higher-kinded-generics-in-java) which is not supported in Java.