# Java generic parametrized parameter constrained by other parameters

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

I have a generic class, which has a function that returns an instance of a functional interface:

```
/**
 * @param <FF> - FF is a functional interface
 */
public abstract class MyFunctionalInterfaceGetter<FF> {
    public abstract <PC, AC> FF getMyFunction(Class<PC> pojoClass, Class<AC> attributeClass);
}
```

And I have a couple of derived classes:

```
public class MyGetterGetter extends MyFunctionalInterfaceGetter<java.util.function.Function> {
    public <PC, AC> Function<PC, AC> getMyFunction(Class<PC> pojoClass, Class<AC> attributeClass) {
         ...
    }
}
```

```
public class MySetterGetter extends MyFunctionalInterfaceGetter<java.util.function.BiConsumer> {
    public <PC, AC> BiConsumer<PC, AC> getMyFunction(Class<PC> pojoClass, Class<AC> attributeClass) {
         ...
    }
}
```

**And the question**:
I do not thing so, but I wanted to know if there is any way to constrain the returning parametrized type from the function parameters at the parent class.
Something like this:

```
public abstract class MyFunctionalInterfaceGetter<FF> {
    public abstract <PC, AC> FF<PC, AC> getMyFunction(Class<PC> pojoClass, Class<AC> attributeClass);
}
```

I am using Java-8

Comment: `<FF>` has no bounds at all, so there could be subclasses like `class X extends MyFunctionalInterfaceGetter<Thread> { … }` or `class Y extends MyFunctionalInterfaceGetter<Callable<String>> { … }` You can not enforce specific type parameters when you didn’t even enforce a parameterized type (with exactly two type parameters) in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, Holger, for replying.

The thing is that the parameters of FF are dynamic, and depend on the invocation to <b>getMyFunction</b>
(the parameters are decided at every <b>getMyFunction</b> invocation)

As the derived classes can enforce those bounds, I can work with the derived types.
But this makes that you cannot work with objects of the base type if you want FF to be bounded

Comment: You can not work with the base type anyway. As said, `FF` can be anything, including just `java.lang.Object`. There’s no point in being able to say “*I don’t know (not even remotely) what it is, but whatever it is, it’s parameterized with X and Y*”. A type `X<A,B>` can be subtype of `Y<B,A>` or even `Z<Q,W>` with no relationship between `Q`, `W`, `A`, and `B`. Type arguments are only useful if you have an actual parameterized type giving them a meaning.

Comment: @FranciscoJavierRojas Are you looking for higher-kinded generics? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876948/higher-kinded-generics-in-java https://medium.com/@johnmcclean/simulating-higher-kinded-types-in-java-b52a18b72c74

Comment: Thank you Dmytro, for your answer, yes, it looks very similar to what I am looking for.
It seems that it is not supported by Java Generics.

Comment: It seems you are right, +1, Holger

Answer (score 0):

Move the generics to the class level and apply if to its subtypes:

```
public abstract static class MyFunctionalInterfaceGetter<FF, PC, AC> {
    public abstract FF getMyFunction(Class<PC> pojoClass, Class<AC> attributeClass);
}
```

```
public static class MyGetterGetter<PC, AC> extends MyFunctionalInterfaceGetter<Function<PC, AC>, PC, AC> {

    @Override
    public Function<PC, AC> getMyFunction(Class<PC> pojoClass, Class<AC> attributeClass) {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
public static class MySetterGetter<PC, AC> extends MyFunctionalInterfaceGetter<BiConsumer<PC, AC>, PC, AC> {

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<PC, AC> getMyFunction(Class<PC> pojoClass, Class<AC> attributeClass) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Nikolas, for your answer.

The thing is that I want the parameters of FF are dynamic, and to depend on every invocation to "getMyFunction".

This approach makes that you can work with only one object of "MyFunctionalInterfaceGetter"